# Missing html elements when reading URL from java

Tags: java, html, web-scraping

I use this code to fetch html code from URL in java

```
        URL url = new URL("..");

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        String html = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println(html);
```

It works fine, i can see that it return a html code.

The problem is that when i use my URL in chrome and i display the page source code I figured out that the html returned in my java code is missing some html elements !!

So i am missing something ?

**SOLUTION**

We specify `user agent` and it works

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("...")
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
      .referrer("http://www.google.com")
      .get();
```

Comment: What html elements are you saying are missing?

Comment: Maybe these elements are generated via javascript?

Comment: @Naros i miss some divs.

Comment: @MadMatts no i don't think so.